# Can't see variable name list when subsetting dataset in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm using R studio on a Macbook pro - This just started happening. I've tried re-downloading R & R Studio and it seems to be a recurring issue. Not sure if I have a setting applied that's making this happen - but any help would be great!

Shown below, when I try to subset variables within the dataset (MFP_Post) all the variables are on the left hand side, where I can't read any of the names.

[image]

Comment: Move your console to the right side of RStudio.  See if that helps

Comment: I would suggest that you consider [resetting](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State) your desktop installation of [tag:rstudio].

Comment: Plus you could just do `names(MFP_Post)` *in* the console in the meantime.